# Is there a 180HP conversion available for a 2011 160HP Cessna 172R with a Garmin G1000?

Tags: piston-engine, cessna-172, stc

I've recently purchased a 2011 172R (160HP) with a G1000 on the sellers promise that I can apply a propeller switch and modified air intake STC to get the derated engine back to 180HP. However, the holder of said STC, AirPlains, shows the kit is only applicable to 1996-2004 172Rs without a G1000. Are there any other manufacturers that can apply this conversion on a later-model 172R, or am I stuck with my 160HP?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but it looks like the [AirPlains kit](http://www.airplains.com/cessna-172-r-conversion#kit-accessories) replaces the tach and ASI. In a G1000 aircraft, that would presumably mean a software change of some kind, and it's likely that Garmin doesn't provide one. I suspect the G1000 is the limiting factor, not the mechanical systems.

Comment: Rookie mistake.  Plane sellers will say almost anything to sell a plane.  Never ever take the word of a seller.  Always demand proof for a claim.  Fear not, however, you may be able to get away with a field approval.  Contact your FSDO for insight into what they will require to approve a 337.

Comment: It's not the approval that's the big problem @acpilot, its the fact that the kit isn't compatible with the G1000.

Comment: @pondlife ahhh that makes so much sense, why didn't I think of that?

Comment: Ya @acpilot I'm really lucky I caught it before money changed hands. Still gonna do it because it's a good deal at 160 or 180HP, but lesson learned.

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but I looked at this a couple years ago.  I have a 2005 172R G1000 in a flight school and students tend to go to the 180hp planes, so I looked into the upgrade.  I did find that Cessna did a STC for a limited, sequential group of Serial Number 172R G1000's.  I believe they might have been done for Embry Riddle, but not positive.  I actually found this out from FAA when I was calling them about a STC or Field upgrade.  Got to the same point as your e-mail string.
Bottom line - it has been done.  It can be done.
When I called Cessna about the details they did tell me the block of SN's it applied to, but after that they would not share anything.
After looking into this again today, talking to Air Planes (they are very nice, and they would love to be able to sell a kit for this!) and remembering my conversations - I think I'll do some digging again.  I'll post if I find anything
Mark - 191CA

Comment: Thank you so much, Mark! Sounds like there's a path as long as you're willing to harass the right people enough, as usual haha. Your answer gives me renewed energy, I'll try and get ahold of Cessna and let you know what I find as well. Thanks!